# Use ActionScript NetStream.Publish to publish AAC audio

Tags: actionscript, streaming, rtmp, aac, wowza

I'm using Flash to play a RTMP stream to a Wowza server.

I publish my microphone with

```
m_MicStream.publish ("mic_user1", "live");
```

Unfortunately, my receiving end only supports AAC audio. Is there a way to publish AAC audio with Flash?

**Note :** I tried the `mp4:mic_user1`, but it does not work. The stream negociation seems ok, but the received audio is garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Flash doen't support AAC audio encoding.
The only way to solve this in Flash side is using Flash Media Live Encoder (even with an AIR app what communicates with that) with this plugin:

http://www.mainconcept.com/products/apps-plug-ins/plug-ins-for-adobe/aac-encoder.html